# Generate a PDF file from JSON data using a given template

Tags: javascript, html, json, pdf

I've been given task by a company to qualify for the final round of interview. I'm not sure how to proceed with it. Details about the same are as under.

Assignment: Generate a PDF file from JSON data using a given template

Description: Using a sample data file (of JSON Format) containing information like patient data, demonstrate the generation of a formatted PDF file using a formatting template. The program should be generic enough to use any such formatting templates for the given set of data. You may use of any of the programming languages - Java/C++/C#.

Here is the json data

`{"medicalRecord":{"name": "Rahul", "dob": "2000-07-09","Languages known/speak":"",  "Gender":"",  "Address":"", "phone":"",  "E-mail":"",   "Medical Details":"",   "Date":"",   "Signature":""}}`

Here is the formatting template.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .myClass { font-size : 18px; padding-left: 20px; } 
        </style>
        <title>
            Medical Report
        </title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div align="left" style="color: #0900C4; font: Helvetica 12pt;border: 1px solid black;" class="myClass">
            <div align="center" >
                <h1>
                    <u>
                        Medical Report
                    </u>
                </h1>
            </div>
            <div style="padding-left: 1000px;" >
                Date :
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div style="padding-left: 1000px;">
                Time:
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div style="padding-left: 20px;">
                Name :
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="myClass">
                DOB :
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="myClass">
                Age :
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="myClass">
                Languages known/speak :
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="myClass">
                Gender :
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="myClass">
                Address :
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="myClass">
                phone :
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="myClass">
                E-mail :
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div class="myClass">
                Medical Details :
            </div>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <div style="padding-left: 1000px;">
                Signature :
            </div>
            <br/>
            <div style="padding-left: 1000px;">
                Date :
            </div>
            <br/>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can go for some libraries like iText etc that can make your task easy.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I tried getting help from iText but I'm not sure where in iText to find exact solution to my query. Can you help me further with it?

Comment: [this](http://www.rgagnon.com/javadetails/java-html-to-pdf-using-itext.html) can help you in starting with.

Comment: Yeah, this helps. Thank you so much.

Comment: I'm trying to develop this project in Eclipse, what all .jar files do I need to add to the build path of the Eclipse project, can you please tell me?

Comment: You can find it here [iText jar file](https://sourceforge.net/projects/itext/)

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a PDF API for your task. Typically, most convert HTML to PDF, meaning your template must be written in HTML.

Alternatively, consider a [LaTeX API](https://advicement.io/dynamic-documents-api), such as DynamicDocs API. DynamicDocs is a [JSON to PDF](https://advicement.io/dynamic-documents-api/json-to-pdf-templates) API which uses templates written in LaTeX. LaTeX has a steep learning curve but can be advantageous over HTML to PDF conversion (high-quality output for example).

Disclaimer: I am involved in developing DynamicDocs API.